"In Himmels Rosen weiden" - Dropping the reflexive pronoun
In Bach's cantata BWV 140, the verb 'weiden' is used when it seems like it must mean 'sich weiden':

Ich will mit dir in Himmels Rosen weiden,

Bach scholars Marissen and Melamed on bachcantatatexts.org write "By dint of the biblical allusion, the cantata line’s “weiden” should presumably be understood as if it were the reflexive “sich weiden.” Otherwise, this line might seem to talking about feeding upon roses in heaven."
I recently came across this in a chorale in the St Matthew Passion:

Hat uns doch dein Sohn verglichen
Durch sein' Angst und Todespein.

Again, going by the dictionary, a common translation of something like "Your son has settled the account for us" seems like it would need a reflexive for sich vergleichen.
Am I understanding the second example correctly, and if so does anyone have any insights into what is going on? Is omitting the reflexive pronoun in older poetic texts not unheard of?

Consult a dictionary. "Weiden" isn't exclusively reflexive. "Die Kühe weiden hinter dem Zaun". And "I want to graze in heaven's roses" is exactly what the sentence is saying (that's obviously not to be taken literally...). And the same is true for "vergleichen" (but note this has an archaic additional meaning like "to compensate" that most dictionaries ignore..

My question is precisely about the fact that it is not exclusively reflexive. The Marissen/Melamed quote is saying that they specifically think 'graze' does not make sense in context. The full quote: In Song of Songs 6:2, the Luther Bibles of Bach’s day read “Mein Freund ist hinab gegangen in seinen Garten, zu den Würzgärtlein, dass er sich weide unter den Garten und Rosen breche”. By dint of the biblical allusion, the cantata line’s “weiden” should presumably be understood as if it were the reflexive “sich weiden.” Otherwise, this line might seem to talking about feeding upon roses in heaven.

(“My beloved is gone down into his garden, to the little herb-gardens, so that he may revel [or, ‘feast his eyes’] among the gardens, and may pick roses”).

It is important to take into account that the German spoken at Bach's time was different from current German. Not looking for those differences in the language is a hermeneutic mistake.
An interpretation (or translation) of the phrase Ich will mit dir in Himmels Rosen weiden. also has to take into account that the sentence is clearly a metaphor, so trying to decipher it in a literal manner will fall short of acknowledging the poetic use of language that might be present in it.
The two scholars you cite might have fallen for both of these mistakes.
Weiden
I am not an expert (not at all) in the German of Bach's time. So my insights are quite limited. That being said, there is an example from another famous work of Bach: Jesu, Meine Freude, Meines Herzens Weide., meaning as much as "Jesus, my joy, longing (?) of my heart" (my translation). Here Weide is clearly used in a semantic proximity, maybe even as a synonym for Freude "joy".
While sich weiden has a negative connotation these days, I would reckon that this is of a more recent date. I guess the difference between weiden and sich weiden that is present was not as prominent in Bach's days. It is also possible that the librettist was playing with words to indicate not just joy, but also a sense of nurturing. But this is speculation. It is impossible for me to say whether this use of language was archaic at Bach's times already. But the parallel to Meines Herzens Weide is a convincing argument for assuming that the meaning of weiden was not just limited to "to graze". Both meanings of sich weiden and weiden contain the concept of taking something in, and enjoying it. Those connotations are backed by the etymology of the word which has meanings of "to put one's eye on something", "to long for something".
Another indicator for this meaning of (the non reflexive form of) weiden is the word Augenweide, roughly "eye candy", "feast for the eyes", that still exists in current German. An Augenweide is something so beautiful that it is hard or impossible to take one's eyes off it. So, weiden carries the connotations of an obsessive joy here.
These are the connotations I read both in Meines Herzens Weide and in Ich will mit dir in Himmels Rosen weiden.
Vergleichen
vergleichen has two meanings nowadays: "to compare" and "to settle (a conflict)". The latter one is relevant here. It is still used with this meaning today but its use is limited to legal jargon. When a litigator asks "Wollen wir uns vergleichen?", he doesn't suggest a comparison, but to make a deal outside of court. Context makes clear that it can be translated as "to reconcile" here.

Thanks, yes when you say "I guess the difference between weiden and sich weiden that is present was not as prominent in Bach's days" that is what I was thinking ('Is omitting the reflexive pronoun in older poetic texts not unheard of?'). Since the two professors are Americans, I also think they might miss something that a native would know. I don't get your point re "Wollen wir uns vergleichen?/Wir haben uns verglichen." though - by my understanding that is indeed reflexive, with 'uns' as the reflexive pronoun?

@Arbace I would call a pronoun reflexive if it translates to "oneself", or "ourselves" (as in wir waschen uns). In this case it translates to "each other" / "one another" (as in wir lieben uns). The difference is not marked in German, as it is "uns" in both cases in German. I am not 100% sure about the common terminology. The latter might be called reflexive, and the first could be called a "true reflexive". I would prefer to not call the latter reflexive. Irregardless of terminological questions, it is this difference that I want to refer to.

Recognizing that the pronoun wir vergleichen uns is not (truly) reflexive, makes it easier to understand how er vergleicht uns is possible.  That would be harder to explain if wir vergleichen uns was truly reflexive.

I had never really thought about the difference, but I see now there is the concept of 'echte und unechte reflexive Verben'. Sorry to drag this on, but how would you change the object of 'Hat uns doch dein Sohn verglichen' to ich or du? 'Er hat mich/dich verglichen'? And how would you understand it/translate it to English?

@Arbace There is no point in changing the object to a singular, because uns means "each other" here, which makes no sense in singular. If I had to make up a terminology, I would call this a reciprocal pronoun, but I have never heard the term :D

If it wouldn't make sense then maybe the original translation is misleading - "Your son has settled the account for us". If it isn't then I would think it should be possible to say "Your son has settled the account for me". Do you have a different translation for "Hat uns doch dein Sohn verglichen" ?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@JonathanHerrera: "The difference is not marked in German, as it is "uns" in both cases in German." This is utterly wrong! "Wir lieben uns" vs. "Wir lieben einander."

@bakunin It is the other way around. While it is possible to express "each" other, uns is ambiguous nonetheless and can both mean "ourselves" and "each other".

"weiden" has actually two vastly different meanings:

in a non-reflexive use it means "to graze":


Die Kühe weiden auf der Wiese.

There is also a noun "die Weide", which means "the meadow" (although there is also a second meaning for the word: a "willow-tree", but that only as an aside).

used in a reflexive form it means "to delight" but with a very negative connotation: say, a torturer might take delight in the pain of his victims:


Er weidet sich an den Qualen seiner Opfer.

"sich weiden" is taking delight in (watching) something very bad happening.
What Bachs text means is clearly the first variant: he wants to graze in heavens (heavenly) roses with you. This makes sense because mankind is regularly pictured as cattle ("sheep") with god as the shepherd.
"Vergleichen" is a similar case, the verb also exists in a reflexive and a non-reflexive form.

non-reflexive it means "to compare":


Ich vergleiche A und B.

I compare A und B. This word has no incidental or implicit meanings, only neutral "to compare".

"sich vergleichen" (reflexive) is a term coming from the jargon of law: "Vergleich" (the noun) is a "settlement". Basically, in a civil law suit, the parties agree to some compromise and the judges role is only to watch that the compromise is within the lawful bounds.

Quite often this takes the form of one party agreeing to pay some compensation and the other agrees to not further press charges. I believe (not sure, I'm not a lawyer) this is called an "out-of-court settlement" in case law.
If you are one of the parties you could, once you have reached the settlement agreement, say:

Ich habe mich (mit dem Prozessgegner) verglichen.

This has no direct translation into English, basically it means you have reached/agreed to such a settlement with the other party.
This is the meaning behind the second sentence: basically, the final judgement is thought of as a literal lawsuit and Jesus reached a settlement with the other party (god) with his pain as the contribution of our behalf and gods forgiveness as his contribution.
EDIT: to clarify

er hat uns verglichen

is a (perhaps poetic) short form of "he has reached a settlement on our behalf", so he has not "sich verglichen", but "uns verglichen".
How the logic behind this sentence works (after all, Jesus claims to be god, so god insists to kill himself; also: a settlement stipulating one party killing the other - or even himself - would be stopped by every responsible judge because such a settlement would be illegal), but there is rarely logic in superstition, so there.

"Sich an etwas weiden" impliziert keineswegs etwas Negatves. Das Negative steckt allein in "Qualen seiner Opfer", nicht im weiden. Im Gegenteil macht der Genuss des Weidens ja gerade den Kontrast zu den Leiden aus. Im Normalfall weidet man sich an der Stimmung eines Sonnenuntergangs am Meer oder der Schönheit einer Musikaufführung usw.

@userunknown: first off: this thread is in English, please respect that. Second: no, "sich weiden" is always related to some negative feelings of someone else one relishes. To use your example: "einen Sonnenuntergang genießen", but "sich an anderer Qualen weiden".

Du liegst falsch, @bakunin. Siehe https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/weiden wo 3a und 3b das Gleiche bezeichnen, aber Duden glaubt tatsächlich, 3b würde abwertend gebraucht, nicht verstehend, dass Sadismus u. Schadenfreude auch von mehreren Leuten geteilt werden können und einer etwa sagen könnte: "Ich habe mich an der Abfuhr der Demokraten geweidet", und er würde das sicherlich nicht abwertend gegenüber sich selbst meinen.

Apropos: 3a und 3b sind außerdem schlicht Metaphern für den Vorgang des Weidens von Vieh.

@userunknown Please use English in the comments, if you are able to. The reason of this principle is to be most helpful to the person asking the question and to future readers - which is the whole point of this site.

@JonathanHerrera: Und ich dachte, Ziel der Seite sei es, den Besuchern Deutsch zu vermitteln!

@userunknown Ja, ist es auch. Aber das geht eben manchmal besser auf Englisch. Wenn OP auf Englisch fragt, ist das die beste Schätzung dafür, welche Sprache ihm/ihr am besten weiterhilft.

Dafür gibt es keinerlei Evidenz und es ist nicht mal plausibel. Außerdem soll es hier ja nicht primär um Fragesteller gehen, sondern um Fragen, die auch für andere Besucher der Seite interessant sind. Und da sind natürlich auf einer Seite über die Sprache Deutsch Deutsch selbst die geeignetste Sprache.
